# What is the PHP equivlent of fromCharCode?

Tags: php, unicode, fromcharcode

Is there a PHP function that takes an integer and return the Unicode character of that number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, but you can easily make one:

```
<?php
/**
 * Return unicode char by its code
 *
 * @param int $u
 * @return char
 */
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
?>
```

Taken from: **[PHP Manual - chr - comments](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#88611)**

Answer (score -1):

Look at this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php