# How to convert 00B0 (degree sign) unicode character?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have string 00B0 which is Unicode of degree sign how can I convert in to symbol?

```
var str = "00B0";
var degreeSign = convesion(str);
console.log(degreeSign);
```

How it possible ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878483/php-equivlent-of-fromcharcode/9878531#9878531 One for PHP

Answer (score 13):

```
console.log('\u00B0');​​​​​​ // outputs ° in my chrome console
```

so basically: '\u00B0'

Comment: This is how it is done. [MDN - Values, Variables and Literals: Unicode escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Unicode_escape_sequences). You can add this link and  remove the "This works for me" to improve your answer.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that a string `'00B0'` can't easily be converted into a string `'\u00B0'`. The string literal `'\u00B0'` is a single character, but `'\u' + str` doesn't work to produce that. You would need to create code for the string literal and then execute the code to get the string.

Answer (score 5):

Parse the string into a number to get the character code, then use the `String.fromCharCode` method to create a string from it:

```
var degreeSign = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str, 16));
```

Comment: Thanks,
Now I have String that contain certain special character(in Unicode string). How can i decode it.
E.g

    var str = "002E002C002D0021003F0040007E005F000A005C002F002600220027003B005E007C003A00280029003C007B007D003E005";

any idea ?
please...

Comment: @PareshThummar: Take four characters at a time from the string and parse them as above: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/DXf3R/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Unicode characters in HTML by following this example

```
&#x00B0;
```

The degrees sign will appear like so: °

edit: Except this question is tagged as Node.js. What is the purpose of getting the symbol? Is it front-end or back-end?

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure your string is well formed, you could also do it like this:

```
var degreeSign = eval("('\\u" + str + "')");
```