# Loop from A to Z in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I loop from A to Z? I'd like to populate a select menu with the letters of the alphabet, eg

```
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    ...
    <option>Z</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use char codes: [JavaScript Char Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

```
for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    $('#select_id_or_class').append('<option>' + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with the following

```
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
    $.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
        $('.example-select-menu').append($('<option>' + alphabet[letter] + '</option>'));
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617123/javascript-associative-array-with-alphabets-as-keys) demonstrates the nice idea that you do not need a hardcoded string. In short:

`for (i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
     arr[i-65] = String.fromCharCode(i).toLowerCase();
}`

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid having numbers like `65` in your code if you just use `charCodeAt()` and `fromCharCode()`.

Print letters from `a` to `z`:

```
for(let i = 'a'.charCodeAt(0); i <= 'z'.charCodeAt(0); i++) {
  $('#select_id_or_class').append(
    '<option>' + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</option>'
  );
}
```

Or:

```
const aCharCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);

for(let i = aCharCode; i <= (aCharCode + 26); i++) {
  $('#select_id_or_class').append(
    '<option>' + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</option>'
  );
}
```

If you want the uppercase characters, replace `'a'.charCodeAt(0)` with `'A'.charCodeAt(0)`

Answer (score 1):

#### One-Liner and Fastest

```js
"<option>"+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('').join("</option><option>")+"</option>"
```

```js
const select = document.createElement("select"); /* select your 'select' tag instead*/
select.style.width = "100px"; /* for demo */
select.innerHTML =
  "<option>"+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('').join("</option><option>")+"</option>";
 /* to generate A-Z options */
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ascii value of A to Z, append options in select using jQuery

```js
for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    $('#select').append('<option>' + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</option>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='select'>

</select>
```