# array of output bytes difference version of php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm using a function that transcribes strings into a byte array, I have this function in PHP and JavaScript but both have different behaviors when I play these characters: 㬁愃膘ƘჀ䚐⦀飠噋&ӡ๨㏃棱쌌ص䌠

How to make the results are the same?

My code:

```
function bytesFromWords($string) {
    $bytes = array();
    $j = strlen($string);

    for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
        $char = ord(mb_substr($string, $i, 1));
        $bytes[] = $char >> 8;
        $bytes[] = $char & 0xFF;
    }
    return $bytes;
}
echo bytesFromWords('㬁愃膘ƘჀ䚐⦀飠噋&ӡ๨㏃棱쌌ص䌠'); // result: 0,227,0,172,0,129,0,230,0,132,0,131,0,232,0,134,0,152,0,198,0,152,0,225,0,131,0,128,0,228,0,154,0,144,0,226,0,166,0,128,0,233,0,163,0,160,0,229,0,153,0,139,0,38,0,211,0,161,0,224,0,185,0,168,0,227,0,143,0,131,0,230,0,163,0,177,0,236,0,140,0,140,0,216,0,181,0,228,0,140,0,160


function bytesFromWords (string) {
    var bytes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var char = string.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(char >>> 8);
        bytes.push(char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}
console.log(bytesFromWords('㬁愃膘ƘჀ䚐⦀飠噋&ӡ๨㏃棱쌌ص䌠').toString()); // result: 59,1,97,3,129,152,1,152,16,192,70,144,41,128,152,224,86,75,0,38,4,225,14,104,51,195,104,241,195,12,6,53,67,32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

- `strlen` does not count Unicode characters as expected.
- `ord` not work with unicode as expected.
- `chr` not work with unicode as expected.

### Problem with `strlen`

`'㬁愃膘ƘჀ䚐⦀飠噋&ӡ๨㏃棱쌌ص䌠'.length` returns 17 and `strlen('㬁愃膘ƘჀ䚐⦀飠噋&ӡ๨㏃棱쌌ص䌠')` returns 46, for fix it, use:

```
$j = preg_match_all('/.{1}/us', $string, $data);
```

### Problem with `ord`

Using `'㬁'.charCodeAt(0)` returns 15105 and `ord('㬁')` returns 227, for fix use:

```
function unicode_ord($char) {
    list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
    return $ord;
}
```

<sub>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333307/1518921</sub>

### Problem with `chr`

Using `String.fromCharCode(15104)` returns `㬁` and `chr(15104)` return empty/blank, for fix use:

```
function unicode_chr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
```

<sub>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878531/1518921</sub>

---

Full code:

```
<?php
function unicode_ord($char) {
    list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
    return $ord;
}

function unicode_chr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}

function bytesToWords($bytes) {
    $str = '';
    $j = count($bytes);

    for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i += 2) {
        $char = $bytes[$i] << 8;
        if ($bytes[$i + 1]) {
            $char |= $bytes[$i + 1];
        }
        $str .= unicode_chr($char);
    }
    return $str;
}

function bytesFromWords($string) {
    $bytes = array();
    $j = preg_match_all('/.{1}/us', $string, $data);
    $data = $data[0];

    foreach ($data as $char) {
        $char = unicode_ord($char);
        $bytes[] = $char >> 8;
        $bytes[] = $char & 0xFF;
    }
    return $bytes;
}


$data = bytesFromWords('㬁愃膘ƘჀ䚐⦀飠噋&ӡ๨㏃棱쌌ص䌠');

echo implode(', ', $data), '<br>';
echo bytesToWords($data);
```

Comment: Getting the length of a Unicode string is typically done with `mb_strlen()` and not with `preg_match_all()` :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck is that instead of using `mb_strlen` and `mb_substr` I used the `preg_match_all` to simplify :) Note that this is not necessary to get one character at a time.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there; I would have expected you to just `foreach ($data[0] as $char) { ... }` :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck I typically use "foreach" for associative arrays type. Do you agree? Thanks :)

Comment: `foreach` can be used for either and is actually faster, too :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck I agree. See For: 29.603ms / Foreach: 0.643ms... I will update code, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses UCS-2 encoding for Unicode strings, so in order to achieve the same ordinal representation you first have to convert your string, e.g. by using [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) or [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) if preferable.

A trick to get ordinal values from a string quickly is by using [`unpack()`](http://php.net/unpack).

```
function bytesFromWords($string)
{
    $x = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UCS-2', 'UTF-8');
    $data = unpack('C*', $x);
    return array_values($data);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/316748)

Answer (score 1):

You use `mb_substr()` which may return you multibyte strings (even if it's just one codepoint).

But `ord()` doesn't like that… it will only take the first passed **byte** (not character).

To get what you want, you should just split the string and take the single bytes:

```
$bytes = str_split($string);
foreach ($bytes as &$chr) {
    $chr = ord($chr);
}
```

Yes, this is **not** the same than you have in Javascript. In Javascript you get codepoint identifier via `string.charCodeAt()`, not the UTF-8 byte sequence.

A trick to get the bytes in Javascript would be (Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729536 ~ [Jonathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski)):

```
var utf8 = unescape(encodeURIComponent(string));

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
    arr.push(utf8.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

But if you wanted the unicode identifier in PHP… just do a quick search for it (e.g. [How to get code point number for a given character in a utf-8 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395832/how-to-get-code-point-number-for-a-given-character-in-a-utf-8-string))